# What LaTeX library do you use for adding graphs to your papers?

Tags: graphs

the expression "graphs" in the title refers to graphs as they are thought in computer science:

Let G = (V(G), E(G)) be a graph. It is a tuple with a set of vertices and edges.

Comment: You can create graphs using the [tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270543/draw-a-graph-in-latex-with-tikz) package.

Comment: I don't think "What do you use for..."? questions are a good fit here.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  Instead, please identify the criteria you will use for evaluating answers.  I am not sure whether the community will consider this question to be on-topic.  You might want to search on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AshwinGanesan I was about to upvote your comment. Then your link to tikz confuses me a bit. Why not the first hit on [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=tikz) or [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) or [the lists of questions tagged "tikz-pgf"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf?sort=votes) that shows more than 30,000 questions or [the info page for tag "tikz-pgf"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikz-pgf/info)?

Comment: @JohnL. My comment was just to bring tikz to the OP’s radar. The OP can take it from there.

Comment: @AshwinGanesan Sorry if I am being dense. A link like that raises my suspicion that it is being used to promote something else (such as your were the answerer, which seem not true).